# ¿Cómo pasar un model de tipo List a una función de js para recorrer su contenido con un for o foreach?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvc, razor

Mi model es una lista `@model List<Librery_MVC.Models.Libro>`. ¿Cómo puedo pasar el model a una función de js para recorrer su contenido con un for o foreach ?.

aca el cshtml:

```html
@model List<Librery_MVC.Models.Libro>
@using Librery_MVC.Models;
@using Librery_MVC.Services;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "pruebalistar";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UsserLayout.cshtml";
    Autor autor = new Autor();
    Categoria category = new Categoria();
    Editorial editorial = new Editorial();
    AutorService sa = new AutorService();
    CategoriaService cs = new CategoriaService();
    EditorialService es = new EditorialService();
    List<Autor> autorList = new List<Autor>();
    List<Categoria> categoryList = new List<Categoria>();
    autorList = sa.ListAutores();
    categoryList = cs.getAllCategories();

    TempData.Keep("User");
}
```

Y acá quiero pasar el modal al parámetro de mi función de js, tengo algo asi hecho en js, lo que pasa es que no se como obtener el modal desde js.

```js
var modal = //aca necesito obtener el @model List<Librery_MVC.Models.Libro>

function recorrerModal(Modal) {

  for (var valor of Modal) {
   console.log("Valor: " + valor);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Que framework estas usando?, porfavor edita la pregunta y pon el framework o frameworks y lenguajes que estas usando en la pregunta,  si me dices que es Java puro entonces hay algo que anda muy mal por aqui...

Comment: gracias @Riven por responder! , esta aclarado en las etiquetas, estoy usando framework MVC y razor, es decir lenguaje c#.

Comment: Menos mal... es que algunos lenguajes se parecen tanto que es dificil a vecez decir cual de todos es,  yo inlcuso pense que estabas usando Java y Javascript,  enrealidad se trata de C#.

Comment: Saludos. Siento te falta incluir lo que tienes y donde tienes el problema. He trabajado similar, pero recibiendo via Ajax el Array de Objetos (que mencionas); o ¿es en tu Vista que quieres procesar una lista no precisamente en JavaScript?

Comment: hola @ RobertoLeOr! acabo de editar el codigo en la pregunta para ver si se entiende mejor. Vuelvo a explicar, en mi View tengo el model (es una lista). quiero pasar ese model al parametro de mi funcion de javascript para recorrer con un for cada valor del modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Puedes guardar tu lista en una variable con formato json 
  var modal = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    
//Y recorres todas las claves que te devuelve el json con los valores
  function recorrerModal() {
     for (var i in modal) {
        console.log(i, modal[i]);
     }
  }
```

Comment: gracias @Jefferson Cuji funciona perfecto!!!